# how to efficiently perform regression using groups of variables

Tags: r, regression

Is there a way of doing the following in R ? I mean by using only the functionality native to R.

Say I have a data frame, df, with 8 columns: x1 to x8.
And I want to regress x8 on x1 to x7.

Let's denote the variables (x1, x2, x3) as P.
And the variables (x4, x5, x6) can be Q.

Given these definitions, is there a way for me to execute something like the following more succinctly ?

`model = lm(x8 ~ (x1 + x2 + x3) * (x4 + x5 + x6) + x7, data=df)`

As it stands, I just cobble stuff together with paste() and plop it into as.formula().

`model = lm(as.formula(paste(stmt, sep="")), data=df)`

Consider also that this isn't for a particular analysis. If there's a simple way of doing it, great. If not, I'll just use duct tape like I am now.

Comment: Please share the dataframe (df) as well. Try using `dput(df)`, run it and paste the result

Comment: If the regressors are factors use base function [`interaction`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/RHOME/library/base/html/interaction.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could think of is to simply use matrices:

```
P <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
Q <- c("x4", "x5", "x6")
other <- "x7"
response <- "x8"

df2 <- as.matrix(df)
```

Then do:

```
lm(df2[,response] ~ df2[,P] * df2[,Q] + df2[,other])
```

Note that you could subset the matrices outside the formula. ie:

```
p <- df2[,P]
q <- df2[,Q]
o <- df2[,other]
y <- df2[,response]

lm(y ~ p * q + o)
```

---

#### Edit:

invoke the use of `factor`:

```
f <- reformulate(c(P, Q, levels(factor(P):factor(Q)), other), response)
f
x8 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x1:x4 + x1:x5 + x1:x6 + x2:x4 + 
    x2:x5 + x2:x6 + x3:x4 + x3:x5 + x3:x6 + x7

lm(f, df)
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck one can always change the coef names. Or we could subset the matrices and use `lm(Y ~ PP * QQ + OTHER)` where `PP <- df2[,P]` `QQ<- df2[,Q]` etc

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. Grouping the variables is one procedure. Making them interact is another procedure. This works with how I want to organize my code.

Comment: @rcot in that case consider accepting one of the solutions to close the question. You accept the best slution by clicking on the checkmark close the the solution you want

Answer (score 1):

Here are several base R alternatives.  All are short.  The last two give particularly nice formulas.  Also note the modularity here, particularly in (4).  The grouping defined by P and Q is separated from the formula structure and the formula calculation does not involve the data frame and so can be tested independently of it.

**1) outer** Use `reformulate` with `outer`.

```
P <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
Q <- c("x4", "x5", "x6")
other <- "x7"
response <- "y"

fo <- reformulate( c(P, Q, other, outer(P, Q, paste, sep = ":")), response)
fo
## y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x1:x4 + x2:x4 + x3:x4 + 
##    x1:x5 + x2:x5 + x3:x5 + x1:x6 + x2:x6 + x3:x6

lm(fo, data)
```

**2) interaction** This also works to compute `fo`:

```
reformulate( c(P, Q, other, levels(interaction(P, Q, sep = ":"))),
  response)
```

**3) strings** Another approach to computing a `fo` provides for a more compact form through string processing.  (Have incorporated @Ben Bolker's suggestion from the comments into the initial answer.)

```
Paste <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = "+")
PQ <- sprintf("(%s) * (%s)", Paste(P), Paste(Q))
fo <- reformulate(c(other, PQ), response); fo
## y ~ x7 + (x1 + x2 + x3) * (x4 + x5 + x6)

lm(fo, data)
```

**4) substitute**  In this approach we input

1. a list of associations, `L`, and
2. a template `templ` which can be provided either as a formula below or character strings (commented out but could replace the line that follows it).

Having defined the inputs just run the one-liner at the end to generate the final formula.

```
# inputs
L <- list(P = c("x1", "x2", "x3"), 
          Q = c("x4", "x5", "x6"),
          other = "x7",
          response = "y")
# choose either of these as the templ input
# templ <- reformulate(c("P*Q", "other"), "response")
templ <- response ~ P*Q + other

# create formula
do.call("substitute", list(templ, Map(\(x) reformulate(x)[[2]], L)))
## y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3) * (x4 + x5 + x6) + x7
```

Another way to specify the list `L` is the following where `data` is the data frame.

```
L0 <- list(P = 1:3, Q = 4:6, other = 7, response = 8)
L <- Map(\(x) names(data)[x], L0)
```

Comment: Frankly I would have to say don't do this, this is completely impossible to read (to someone else). Just write out the seven variables.

Comment: It doesn't need to be flexible - this is specific analysis, at least as defined in the Q. In fact, I would suggest that if you accidentally changed the data frame,  you should get an error, not potentially a different analysis than  you meant.

Comment: Perhaps. But just because something is possible, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I think you can shorten your last answer to `reformulate(c(PQ, other), response)`: the `*` operator takes care of including the main effects

Comment: @Ben Bolker, Good point. Have incorporated it.

Comment: Have added (3) and (4).